# Meat boy -- 2-18 bandage?

Tags: super-meat-boy

How am i supposed to get the bandage on Chapter 2 level 18? It looks like it's inaccessible. I currently have Commander Video, Gish, and Meat Boy.

Comment: This is out now??  Must get!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven't done this myself, can't get the timing down correctly (I'm absolutely terrible at the game), but found a few forum posts with the specifics of the answers:

http://www.xbox360achievements.org/forum/showthread.php?p=3667626

-or-

http://www.gamespot.com/pages/forums/show_msgs.php?topic_id=27488299

The gist is: wait on the platform next to bandage girl after getting the key, the lasers flash off for a second, and in that time you can jump inside the box (one block is different than the others). There is apparently a secret path out of there once you've gotten the bandage.

**UPDATE:** I did go home and run through this level, and the above descriptions should get you the bandage indeed.